# How to write rules to list all city when asked in query?

Tags: prolog

How to set the rules and when ask the query to list all the cities it works?

```
/*CITY DATABASE */
capital(bern).
capital(london).
capital(prague).
capital(bonn).
capital(belgrade).

city_in(prague,czechoslovakia).
city_in(berlin,germany).
city_in(hamburg,germany).
city_in(belgrade,yugoslavia).
city_in(bern,switzerland).
city_in(london,united_kingdom).

belongs_to(czechoslovakia,’COMECON’).
belongs_to(germany,’EC’).
belongs_to(switzerland,’EFTA’).
belongs_to(united_kingdom,’EC’).

/*END*/
```

Comment: Do not use tags of languages which are not involved.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, are you trying to get the full list of cities available?

Comment: This is a historical data base prior to [1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czechoslovakia).

Answer (score 1):

To get the full list of cities available with this ruleset, the following query will list all of your cities in the X variable (tested in SWI-Prolog):

```
city_in(X, _).
```

To convert the cities into a single list, use `findall/3` (`Xs` will have the result):

```
findall(X, city_in(X, _), Xs).
```

If you're trying to get the list of cities which belong to some organisation, you can issue the following and get both a list of countries and cities which exist in the organisation:

```
belongs_to(Country, _), city_in(X, Country).
```

Again, for a list of responses with `findall/3`:

```
findall(X, (belongs_to(Country, _), city_in(X, Country)), Xs).
```

A list of capital cities which belong to some organisation (listed in the City variable):

```
belongs_to(Country, _), city_in(City, Country), capital(City).
```

And, for a list of cities belonging to an organisation with `findall/3`:

```
findall(City, (belongs_to(Country, _), city_in(City, Country), capital(City)), Cities).
```

Output of the above:

```
?- findall(City, (belongs_to(Country, _), city_in(City, Country), capital(City)), Cities).
Cities = [prague, bern, london].
```

Comment: These queries will produce solutions, but to bundle them up in a list you need to use `setof/3`, `bagof/3` or `findall/3`.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! I'll try that out and update my answer to reflect these.  I'm still new to Prolog myself.

Comment: Answer updated using `findall/3` for list responses.